# changed PGA , SGA sizes but the changes are not reflecting

Tags: oracle, resources

I have changed the PGA and SGA in my system like below. after which we restarted the dB but the changes are not reflected.

This is a RAC DB and has 4 instances

scope=spfile

is there any problem?

```
SQL> alter system set sga_max_size=90g scope=spfile sid = 'OFSAA';

System altered.

SQL> alter system set sga_target=90g scope=spfile sid = 'OFSAA';

System altered.

SQL> alter system set pga_aggregate_target=90G scope =spfile sid='OFSAA';

System altered.

SQL> alter system set pga_aggregate_limit=50G scope =spfile sid='OFSAA';
```

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if sid parameter is incorrectly specified.

Check it with this command:
`select instance_name from v$instance;`

Note that the sid parameter is case sensitive.
For example:
`OFSAA != ofsaa`

Answer (score 0):

After changing the sizes of **PGA SGA**, The OS parameter may restrict the DB on the usage of 100% SGA. To validate this, please check the SGA PGA values from the AWR report.